# What is the use in having the valueOf() function?

Tags: actionscript-3

Why is the valueOf() function present in everything in AS3? I can't think of an instance when this isn't redundant. In terms of getting a value, `x` and `x.valueOf()` are completely the same to me (except that one probably takes more CPU cycles).  Furthermore even though they may not be the same in terms of setting something, `x.valueOf() = y` (if even legal) is just completely pointless.

I am confident though that this is here for a reason that I'm just not seeing. What is it? I did try Googling for a minute. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Returns the primitive value of the specified object. If this object does not have a
>   primitive value, the object itself is returned.

Source: Adobe AS3 Reference [http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Object.html#valueOf()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Object.html#valueOf%28%29)

Edit:

A primitive value can be a Number, int, bool, etc...  They are just the value.  An object can have properties, methods, etc.

Biggest difference, in my opinion though:

```
primitive2 = primitive1;
```

In this example, primitive 2 contains a copy of the data in primitive 1.

```
obj2 = obj1;
```

In this one, however, ob2 points to the same object as obj1.  Modify either obj1 or obj2 and they both reflect the change, since they are references.

In short, valueOf is used when you want to see the primitive representation of an object (if one exists) rather than the object itself.

Comment: I saw this in the documentation earlier, but unless I'm missing something in the wording here, I don't see how this is any different than just pulling from a normal variable or something.

Comment: What does "primitive value" mean?  I ran a quick test using the method an a number of object types, and I'm left scratching my head as well as to the purpose of such a method.

Comment: But if the object is not a primitive, but just a regular object, wouldn't valueOf() invariably return a reference to the object itself (except where overridden)?

Comment: Not if an Object actually has a primitive representation.  I may have a class called Fraction for example.  Fraction would have properties for numerator or denominator.  Yet if I wanted the ValueOf that class, I would just return (numerator/denominator).  Valueof would give me a primitive representation of my Object.  On a raw object with nothing special implemented, yup, it would invariably return the object itself.  I'm just pointing out the distinction and a possible use.

Comment: Is valueOf()'s practical worth dependent on the fact that certain classes might override it to do stuff like that?

Comment: Sure.  It's situational.  In fact, I doubt I'd ever actually use it with my coding style.  That doesn't mean it's pointless or redundant.  It has a purpose, and specific behavior.

Answer (score 2):

As you say, its completely redundant.

The valueOf method is simply included so that ActionScript 3 complies with the ECMA language specification (obviously there are other requirements to be an ECMA language - i believe toString is another example).

Comment: It was a very close call between this and Fillmore's answer; sorry, I had to choose one or the other.  Thank you though.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a clear example between

`Value` Vs. `ValueOf`:

`Value` = `Thu Jan 2 13:46:51 GMT-0800 2014` (`value` is date formatted)

`ValueOf` = `1388699211000` (`valueOf` is in Raw epoch)

Answer (score 1):

`valueOf` isn't useless. It allows an `Object` to provide a value for an expression that expects a [primitive type](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/actionscript/learning/as3-fundamentals/data-types.html). It's available in [AS3](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Object.html#valueOf()) as well as [JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/valueOf).

If someone wrote a function that takes an int, you could pass it your object (more precisely, it passes the result of your object's `valueOf()` function).

The usefulness is tempered by 1) the fact that the Object isn't passed, so it's only an Object in the outermost scope, and 2) the fact that it's a read-only operation, no assignment can be made.

Here're a couple concrete examples off the top of my head:

**Example 1:** A `Counter` class that automatically increments its value every time it's read:

```
class Counter
{
  private var _cnt:int = 0;
  public function Counter() { }
  public function valueOf():int
  {
    return _cnt++;
  }
  public function toString():String { return ""+valueOf(); }
}
```

Usage:

```
var c:* = new Counter();
trace(c);     // 0
trace(c);     // 1
trace(2*c+c); // 2*2+3 = 7
trace(c);     // 4
```

Notes:

- I added the `toString()` pass-through, since functions that take `String` prefer `toString` over `valueOf`.
- You must type c as * and not `Counter`, otherwise you'll get a compiler error about implicit coercion of Counter to Number.

**Example 2:** A (read only) pointer type

Let's say you have an array of ints, and you want to have a reference (aka pointer) to an element in the array. ECMA scripts don't have pointers, but you can emulate one with `valueOf()`:

```
class ArrayIntPointer
{
  private var arr:Array;
  private var idx:int;
  public function ArrayIntPointer(arr:Array,
                                  idx:int)
  {
    this.arr = arr;
    this.idx = idx;
  }

  public function valueOf():int
  {
    return arr[idx];
  }
  public function toString():String { return ""+valueOf(); }
}
```

Usage:

```
  var arr:Array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
  var int_ptr:* = new ArrayIntPointer(arr, 2);

  // int_ptr is a pointer to the third item in the array and
  // can be used in place of an int thanks to valueOf()
  trace(int_ptr); // 3
  var val:int = 2*int_ptr+1;
  trace(val); // 7

  // but it's still an object with references, so I
  // can change the underlying Array, nand now my
  // object's primitive (aka, non-Object types) value
  // is 50, and it still can be used in place of an int.
  arr[2] = 50;
  trace(int_ptr); // 50

  // you can assign int_ptr, but sadly, this doesn't
  // affect the array.
```

That's pretty slick. It'd be really slick if you could assign the pointer and affect the array, but unfortunately that's not possible, as it assigns the `int_ptr` variable instead. That's why I call it a read-only pointer.